# Gparted found problems when "checking" both primary partitions. How to fix?

Tags: partitioning, disk, gparted

I am using Gparted (from Ubuntu Live CD) to enlarge my Win Vista and shrink my Ubuntu 9.04 partitions.
Reports of "check" process on each partition are here:

Vista partition:

[image]

Ubuntu partition:

[image]

Previous to these 2 steps I had made some other partition changes, so probably screwed something up.  I have CDs (and backup personal files) to reinstall the Win Vista, and will use the Ubuntu Live CD to install a new Ubuntu 12.10.

What is the easiest way for me to fix this so I can complete my final 2 steps:

1. Move and shrink the Ubuntu partition
2. Grow the Vista partition

Answer (score 2):

I decided to reformat all partitions and reinstall the Windows Vista and the new Ubuntu 12.10.

I probably created this problem while trying to work with GParted.

### Lessons Learned

1. While I have been using Ubuntu for ~6 years, each time I have a problem upgrading or installing new, **I am a newbie** all over again.
2. Ergo, **always** have a full system install/recovery disc.
3. **Always** have current backups of personal files.

Once I decided that I would reformat & reinstall, I was able to experiment with GParted and ultimately learned a lot about how it works and got pretty confident with it. End results were perfect.

By the way, after doing the install, I had a problem with `grub restore>`.

The following procedure worked perfectly:
[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd/#.USWJWxyYNok)